# infinite scroll firing too quickly with cursor, but fine with space bar or scroll wheel

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to learn React by implementing a custom infinite scroll.

The code works as expected when using the spacebar or mouse scroll wheel to scroll.

But if I drag the scrollbar down (on my desktop computer) with my mouse cursor, the scrolling happens too quickly (because obviously  using the mouse cursor to drag down the scroll bar --> causes the scroll bar to stick to the bottom --> causes the code to fire too many times).

How can I slow down the the infinite scrolling in the mouse cursor case?

```js
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
  
  arr.push(i);

}


class Element extends React.Component{

  render() {
      
      const styleObj = {height: 100, backgroundColor:"hotpink"};
    
      return (<div style={styleObj}> {this.props.data} </div>);

  }
}


class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      visibleStart: 0,
      visibleEnd: 20,
   diff: 20
    };
  }

  render() {

    var arr2 = arr.slice(this.state.visibleStart, this.state.visibleEnd);
    var renderedOutput = arr2.map((item,index) => <Element data={item} key={index}/>)

    return (
      <div>
        {renderedOutput}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this))
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this))
  }
  


 handleScroll(event) {
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()) {
 console.log(this.state.visibleStart + " " + this.state.visibleEnd);
    
 var visibleStart = this.state.visibleStart+ this.state.diff;
 var visibleEnd = this.state.visibleEnd + this.state.diff;
 
 this.setState({
  visibleStart: visibleStart,
        visibleEnd: visibleEnd
      });
 window.scrollTo(0, 300);
 
 console.log(this.state.visibleStart + " " + this.state.visibleEnd);
 }
 console.log($(window).scrollTop());

 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Debounce is the easiest way to get around this issue, only fire a function every so often. Look at Lodash with `_.debounce(func, time);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag, say **allowScroll**:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        visibleStart: 0,
        visibleEnd: 20,
        diff: 20
    };

    this.allowScroll = true;
}
```

And then in your scroll handler use a timeout to prevent unnecessary executions:

```
handleScroll(event) {
    if (!this.allowScroll) {
        return;
    }

    this.allowScroll = false;

    setTimeout(function() {
        this.allowScroll = true;
    }, 1000);

    // ...

 }
```